# How to get data from an old file and compare it with a new file

Tags: php

There is a file, I get its size, and then I overwrite the file, and I need to compare the new size with the old file size, but for some reason I only get the value of the new file

```
$filenameOld = path_to_file;
$fileSize = filesize($filenameOld);

$fp = fopen(path_to_file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);

    $filenameNew = path_to_file;
    $filesizeNew = filesize($filenameNew);

    $sumSize = $filesizeOld - $filesizeNew;
```

$filesizeOld and $filesizeNew =  same

Comment: Post some code, can't tell if you are using the same variable for both, the type you are using, etc.

Comment: maybe it doesn't work that way, but it's very interesting how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Used the`clearstatcache()` function, And everything works